# Good one-off throwaway medium/method for offline data delivery instead of CD/DVDs?

Tags: usb, dvd, data-transfer, cd

I need to deliver a few large-ish data archives (5-20 GB each) to other people in the nearby area, but my internet connection is painfully slow, especially the upload. It takes about 3-6 hours for each GB to upload, so the cloud is not a feasible option.

I was considering burning the archives on throwaway DVDs and just deliver them (personally or shipping by post), but many people don't even have the DVD drives anymore, especially if they only use laptops.

What alternatives do I have?

1. I am not really willing to buy a stack of USB sticks just for this. They are not as cheap as DVDs would be.
2. I could ask the receivers to come by and bring a USB stick, but this requires many people to come to my house (ehm, social distancing?) and each single receiver has to drive to my place (many 2-way trips). Compared to me shipping DVDs via post (1-way trips for the data) or me driving around once for about 1 hour to drop DVDs into multiple nearby mailboxes, it just seems excessively complicated.

Comment: First you should find out how many recipients have DVD drives or are willing to pay the costs of a USB stick.

Comment: It's about 5 people right now, but the situation could repeat in the future for other data archives. They are not willing to pay nor I'm willing to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There ain't no such thing as a free lunch (ie no magic answer)

DVD drives are probably the best bet for reliability if they need to keep an archive copy. USB is good if they need ease of use.

Doing it while social distancing is a problem, but another technical solution would be a USB SSD or SATA SSD+case and copying data to/from it.  SSDs - even SATA ones are by far the fastest way of doing transfers on standard systems - way faster the USB, and way,way faster then DVD.

Impractical IMHO but another way around social distancing  -If you are quite technical and your audience is slightly technical you could build a "router"' with storage, configure an AP and web server on it with web server serving the file archive, power it by battery - eg car battery inverter - and then drive over to them, call them and get them to connect and download it.  Come to think of it, you might even be able to do this all on a cellphone.

If your users are on an ADSL type connection (ie asymmetric connection) , putting the data on USB, going to a well connected place and uploading it may be your best bet. At least in my experience libraries and universities - if you have access to WIFI at them - are good sources of fast Internet.

Comment: USB drive+going to library/university makes probably the most sense - but they are all closed right now. The portable AP solution is more expensive than buying throwaway USB sticks and requires a lot of download time at each recipient's home. A portable SSD is again something I would have to buy in the first place.

Comment: At least here (in New Zealand) library WIFI works even when the library is closed.  Downloading over WIFI can be pretty quick if its done right - often faster then dealing with USB pen drives - I agree its probably not a great solution if you don't already have suitable hardware lying around [ many - I imagine most ] people who are active here would!

Answer (score 1):

Given your limitations (no cloud, no special port & cheaper than USB stick) I don't think there would be any better solution for you.